# How to run code only on first boot in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In some cases, I want my project only run some codes in project start up, for example, I will store the sql statement into redis when the program starts running. In ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Web API, I can let this code write in Application_Start method, so what should I do in .NET Core?

Comment: What version .Net Core are you using ?

Comment: I use .Net Core 2.1

Comment: You can refer to [Migrate from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and check the `Global.asax file replacement` section .